# Blinking text in a form creating by PowerShell

Tags: winforms, powershell, label

I search the way to blink a text label in a windows.form.
This is a part of my script :

```
$Form                              = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.StartPosition                = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
$Form.ClientSize                   = '600,800'
$Form.text                         = "USMT - Sauvegarde des profils"

$Label1                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                       = "1. Chemin vers scanstate.exe :"
$Label1.AutoSize                   = $true
$Label1.width                      = 25
$Label1.height                     = 10
$Label1.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,10)
$Label1.Font                       = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
```

Here I search a solution to blink $Label1.text

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

Create a timer, add an event handler to its `Tick` event and toggle visibility of the label from there. Creating GUIs and reacting to events isn't particularly nice in PowerShell, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` object and set its `Interval` to a suitable value (milliseconds) and then by handling its `Tick` event, do whatever you need to blink the label, for example toggle visibility of the label. You need to start the timer when loading form:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Text = "This is my label."
$label.AutoSize = $true
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 250

$timer.Add_Tick({$label.Visible = -not($label.Visible)})
$form.Add_Load({$timer.Start()})

$form.ShowDialog()
$timer.Dispose()
$form.Dispose()
```